# Strange artifacts in material transparency (viewport)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, transparency

I wonder what's causing this kind of problems and how to get rid of it. I tried to remove doubles and recalculate normals but these don't work. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: They look like internal faces.

Comment: I've checked the mesh using the Mesh Lint addon and there are no internal faces there.

Comment: This is caused by the obsolete blender viewport engine. The alpha faces should be depth-sorted which does not happen and it's a known limitation.

Comment: I think this is just a viewport display bug as Jerryno said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Realtime renderer alpha artifacts

I think is related to the way polygons are drawn from the viewport engine.

To make the viewport render faster, the algorithm *doesn't* take into account whether a face is in front of another, leading to such artifacts. It happens quite the same in other realtime engine like [Sketchfab viewer](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202602073-Transparency) (see *Why order matters* section). This is pefectly understandable: the software should perform much more calculations if it should not takes into account only the face visibility but also the alpha depth.

See in the image sequence below how till I'm stacking the quads one above the other in order (latest on top) all works well, while switching their position leds to wrong results:

[image]

At the end, it seems more important the order in wich faces are "stored" in the file than the alpha&camera-distance factor. The artifacts in the picture comes from a that. Some faces are drawn in front of other even if they are behind.

*There are some freshly implemented viewport alpha options for cycles, like BGE's ones, but despite their promising names, they don't work (yet).*

Here's a reel of the options in **BGE**:

[image]

While in **Cycles** you can only see a difference when "Add" is enabled

[image]

*I personally think developers are "working on it".*

Comment: Thanks for the technical explanation Carlo. Hope this kind of display malfunction'll be fixed in the future Blender releases, cause it looks very ugly. BTW I'm impressed by your large blender knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGonet, for your kindness but it's not much "technical". At the end it's just what I understood so far, I wasn't able to find further references. I wouldn't call it malfunction, nor a bug. It's just "high perfomance mode", and the "beauty/quality mode" is not currently available.